# what practical purpose does Android NDK serve?

Tags: android

I am trying to understand why would anyone want to use the NDK feature in android programming? Is c++ really important to learn for Android ?

Comment: _"Is c++ really important to learn for Android ?"_. Not really, no. But there are other situations where you'd want to use the NDK. For example; you might have some legacy code in C/C++ that you want to use in your application, or you might need better performance than what Java can offer for parts of your application.

Comment: I think it just depends on your application. Native code runs faster than if written in java because it doesn't have to go through a JVM. So for things like graphics or game engines, they're usually either entirely native, or native but wrapped for you with a Java api. Also, sometimes using native libraries might require you to write some native code.

Answer (score 4):

The three (and perhaps a fourth) main reasons are:

- **Performance**.  For some critical inner loops the marginal performance advantage of C/C++ over Java, especially before Just In Time compilation (JIT) is available in the Android compiler, may be a decisive factor.
- **To use existing C/C++ libraries**.  The reasoning here is pretty obvious.
- **To do something that the NDK allows that the Java API can't manage**. Low level operations close to the hardware, particularly to touch manufacturer-specific hardware, might only be possible through C/C++
- As Yojimbo suggested, **obfuscation**.  It's somewhat more difficult to reverse engineer compiled machine code than Java byte code, though you should never count on security by obscurity.

Having said all that, you should be very sure you need the NDK before you decide to use it.  Testing and maintenance costs of NDK code are likely to be higher than equivalent Java.

Comment: To your list I would add "To increase the difficulty of reverse engineering the app".

Answer (score 1):

I've used NDK several times, either for:

- utilizing an existing C library.
- sharing code across platforms (such as iOS) that don't use Java.

NDK is not as useful for performance because Android apps are usually not CPU-bound, but instead wait for network or file access. That's why Google [says](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html):

> Using native code on Android generally does not result in a noticable performance improvement, but it always increases your app complexity.

Comment: thanks for the answers. But can you get even more specific? I mean an actual live example which you used C++ NDK to resolve an issue.

Comment: if you dont mind me asking, do you use javascript at your work place?

Comment: if so, what do u use javascript for ?

Comment: @fishman You should check out Vuforia. It's a free augmented reality engine, and they have sample projects setup are that using part java code and part native code for the rendering and vision tracking. Here's the link if you're interested: https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/android

Comment: I used it for incorporating ffmpeg in one project and pjsip in another, both C libraries. In a third case, I wrote a business logic module in C that interpreted business logic for enterprise policy, which was then used in Android, iOS, OSX and Windows.